# How to access main thread from worker thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Read many [overkilled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604984/how-can-i-get-main-thread-from-thread-currentthread), [overcomplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268693/running-code-on-the-main-thread-from-a-secondary-thread) solution here in SO, for such an easy question, how to access main thread from a worker thread, to execute some code on it.

In iOS `dispatch_get_main_queue()` method returns main thread. How in Java?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0UL), ^{
    //do background thread stuff

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update UI
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running code in main thread from another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123621/running-code-in-main-thread-from-another-thread)

Comment: Neither of the links in your question have anything to do with Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can't access the main thread (UI Thread) directly, but you can queue jobs on it, so you need to create a `Handler` and using that handler to post jobs (`Runnable`) on main thread.

Below is an example of how you can post on `UI Thread` using `Handler`

```
new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Doing job here
      }
    })
```

and also as [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) mentioned in the comments, there is another ways to access UI thread:

- if you have instance of any `View` you can use `View.post(Runnable)`
- if you have instance of `Activity`, you can use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`

---

Btw accessing main thread in Android is totally different than Java Desktop Apps

Comment: You do not need to create a `Handler`, as `post()` is also available on any `View`, and typically you have access to one of those.

Comment: thats one of other solutions

Comment: @CommonsWare his question is how to access main thread from worker thread, so I assumed he doesn't have access to any Views

Answer (score -1):

Running your code on main thread from another:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // Your code here
        }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Curious why the downvote? Explanation? This code works fine to change state of the UI in the `doInBackground()` method of an AsyncTask for example. Is this not the "proper" way?